# How to place dropdowns side by side in Dash,Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

[image]I'm pretty new to dash and trying to place two dropdowns side by side each other but they don't seem to work at all, instead they are below each other. I think I'm messing up in 'className' arrangement of HTML div's. The code is as follows:

```
app.layout = html.Div([

html.Div( [

    html.H1("Web Application Dashboards with Dash", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

 ] ),

html.Div(
className = "row",children =[
    html.Div(className='six columns', children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown_dataset',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'diabetes', 'value': 'diabetes'},
                        {'label': 'Custom Data', 'value': 'custom'},
                        {'label': 'Linear Curve', 'value': 'linear'},
                    ],
                    value='diabetes',
                    clearable=False,
                    searchable=False,
        )])
    ,html.Div(className='six columns', children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown_dataset_2',
        options=[
            {'label': 'sinh', 'value': 'sinh'},
            {'label': 'tanh', 'value': 'cosh'},
        ],
        value='diabetes',[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        clearable=False,
        searchable=False,
    )])
  ])
  ])



  if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1',port = '5000',debug=False,use_reloader=False)
```

Can you point where I'm making the mistake and is there any documentation to refer for this ?

Comment: I think tables or columns... will see what others come up with.

Answer (score 9):

This will do it. I've added `display='flex'` to the div that contains both dropdowns, and set the width to 50% for the divs that contain only single dropdowns. You could certainly set those styles in your CSS file using the IDs or classnames instead of coding them inline like this.

```py
    html.Div(
        className="row", children=[
            html.Div(className='six columns', children=[
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dropdown_dataset',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'diabetes', 'value': 'diabetes'},
                        {'label': 'Custom Data', 'value': 'custom'},
                        {'label': 'Linear Curve', 'value': 'linear'},
                    ],
                    value='diabetes',
                    clearable=False,
                    searchable=False,
                )], style=dict(width='50%'))
            , html.Div(className='six columns', children=[
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dropdown_dataset_2',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'sinh', 'value': 'sinh'},
                        {'label': 'tanh', 'value': 'cosh'},
                    ],
                    value='diabetes',  # [![enter image description here][1]][1]
                    clearable=False,
                    searchable=False,
                )], style=dict(width='50%'))
        ], style=dict(display='flex'))
```

Comment: Great...this works. Also how do I add padding in between them and borders and style the box maybe. Could I give me some sorta reference?

Comment: If you want space between them, reduce their widths. Check out [this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for all the good stuff on how to use flexbox. It will let you then control how the stuff inside the flexbox is spaced. Padding and borders work as normal. Add them to the divs you want to have them.